# ¿Utilizar o Crear Attributes para validacion de datos en propiedades?

Tags: c#, .net

Hola chicos quisiera saber si existen attributes o se pueden crear para propiedades que permitan añadir restricciones como:

-Solo numeros positivos

-Length de una cadena minimo 3 y maximo 255

-No puede ser null

-Solo 1 o 0 representando un binario (true, false)

Etc...

para ayudar a la validacion de datos , ya que trabajo un proyecto con una base de datos y he creado structs que representan las tablas como Cliente,Persona,Producto

Comment: Hola. El proyecto que estás realizando para acceso a datos lo estás implementado con `Entity Framework`?

Comment: nop explicame que es, que si no estoy mal es tener modelos de la base datos.

Comment: Porqué usas structs para representar tablas? ño lógico (y mejor) es usar clases, no structs.

Comment: los struct no permiten null, ni herencias y se usan para datos simples.

Comment: Si hablas de `winforms`, cualquier tipo de validación debes hacerla manualmente. Yo te recomendaría en lugar de una estructura, usar una clase, y hacer las validaciones el el `set` de las propiedades. Debes tener cuidado con las estructuras "mutables", a veces tiene efectos secundarios inesperados, lee por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441357/579895)